# The second argument of python replace function

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, lambda

I would like to sort words in roots, and then replace the sentence by each root. The below code throw me an error

> TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not list

def replace_words(roots, sentence):

```
    for word in sentence.split():
        matches = [root for root in roots if word.startswith(root)]
    #print(matches)
    
        if len(matches) >0:
           sentence = sentence.replace(word, sorted(matches, key=lambda x:len(x)))

    return sentence.strip()
```

But if we add [0] behind sorted( ), it will fix the error:

[image]

Looks like [0] converted the second argument of sorted function from list to string, but I really have trouble understanding what is the underlying process. Could anyone kindly explain it?

Comment: Don't use images for your code. Please paste it instead into the post.

Comment: your index is in the wrong place. you have `sentence.replace(word, sorted(...))[0]`. You want `sentence.replace(word, sorted(...)[0])`

Comment: This may or may not be related, but do you know how you get a specific item from a list (say, the first one)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Add[0] to indicate the first item?

Comment: Yes.  `sorted` on a list returns a list.  You need the first item of a that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking the error...

Does it make sense if you write it like this?

```
sorted_roots = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:len(x))
sentence = sentence.replace(word, sorted_roots)
```

`sorted()` returns a list. `str.replace()` needs 2 string arguments, not a string, *and a list*.

By adding `[0]` to the end of `sorted()`, you've gotten the first element of the sorted list (the shortest root)